# dynamically subseting data.table in R

Tags: r, loops, data.table

my data.table contain `K` columns called `claims`, among other 30 columns. I want to subset the `data.table`, such that only rows remain which do not have 0 claims.

So, firstly i get all the column names i need for filtering. For the purpose of this example, i have chosen `K = 2`

```
> claimsCols = c("claimsnext", paste0("claims" , 1:K))
> claimsCols
[1] "claimsnext" "claims1"    "claims2"
```

i have tried subsetting like:

```
for(i in claimsCols){
  BTplan <- BTplan[ claimsCols[i] == 0, ]
  i+1
}
```

this doent work:

```
Error in i + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would basically do what akrun does

```
idx = BTplan[ , Reduce(`&`, .SD), .SDcols = patterns('claims')]
BTplan = BTplan[idx]
```

The innovations are:

1. Use `patterns` in `.SDcols` to specify the columns to include by pattern
2. `&` automatically converts numeric to logical, i.e. `1.1 & 2.2` is `TRUE`, and becomes `FALSE` as soon as there's a `0` anywhere (hence filtering the corresponding row)

In a future version of `data.table` this will be slightly more efficient and concise (and hopefully more readable):

```
idx = BTplan[ , pall(.SD), .SDcols = patterns('claims')]
BTplan = BTplan[idx]
```

Keep an eye on this pull request:

https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4448

Answer (score 2):

In the OP's code, the `i` is each of the elements of 'claimsCols' which is `character`, so `i +1` won't work and in fact, it is not needed

```
for(colnm in claimsCols) {
      BTplan <- BTplan[BTplan[[colnm]] != 0,]
 }
```

---

Or using `data.table` syntax

```
library(data.table)
setDT(BTplan)
BTplan[BTplan[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, `!=`, 0)),.SDcols = claimsCols]]
```

Comment: i tried the `data.table` syntax, but get an error `Error in `[.data.frame`(BTplan, , Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, `!=`, 0)), .SDcols = claimsCols) : 
  unused argument (.SDcols = claimsCols)`

Comment: @Nneka Looks like your dataset is `data.frame`.  Convert to `dat.atable` with `setDT(BTplan)` and it should work